# Angularjs MVC application, I cannot figure out why I'm getting an Unknown provider: $routeProvider <- $route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I'm working on an application that is using angularjs routing. I've added ngRoute as a dependancy, I have confirmed that the angular-route.js file is being loaded. I still get an unknown provider error $routeProvided <- $route.

What am I missing?

I have three files for my app, they are loaded in the order displayed below.

My application.js file

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
    // Angular modules 
    'ngAnimate',        // animations
    'ngRoute',          // routing
]);

app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$q', 'routemediator',
    function ($route, $rootScope, $q, routemediator) {
        routemediator.setRoutingHandlers();
    }]);
 })();
```

my route config file

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp');

// Configure Toastr
toastr.options.timeOut = 4000;
toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-bottom-right';


var events = {
    controllerActivateSuccess: 'controller.activateSuccess',
    spinnerToggle: 'spinner.toggle'
};

var config = {
    appErrorPrefix: '[Error] ', //Configure the exceptionHandler decorator
    docTitle: 'error: ',
    events: events,
    version: '1.0.0'
};

app.value('config', config);

app.config(['$logProvider', function ($logProvider) {
    // turn debugging off/on (no info or warn)
    if ($logProvider.debugEnabled) {
        $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    }
}]);

app.config(['commonConfigProvider', function (cfg) {
    cfg.config.controllerActivateSuccessEvent =          config.events.controllerActivateSuccess;
    cfg.config.spinnerToggleEvent = config.events.spinnerToggle;
}]);

})();
```

My config file

```
 (function () {
 'use strict';

 var app = angular.module('MyApp');

 // Collect the routes
 app.constant('routes', getRoutes());

// Configure the routes and route resolvers
 app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);
 function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes) {
    alert('in route config');
    routes.forEach(function (r) {
        $routeProvider.when(r.url, r.config);
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home.html' });
}

// Define the routes 
function getRoutes() {

    return [
        {
            url: '/',
            config: {
                title: 'Home',
                templateUrl: '/App/views/Home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                settings: {
                    nav: 1,
                    content: '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home'
                }
            }

        }
    ];
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent verison of Angular (1.2+), you need to download and include the ngRoute file in addition to angular.js, which doesn't include all these side providers anymore.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the second sentence of my question I confirmed that angular-route.js is being loaded.